# Switch QGIS proxy settings programatically

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, network, proxy

I am using QGIS at two offices with different proxy-servers.

At the moment I have to change the proxy settings manually every time i switch the office.

I was wondering if its possible to change the proxy-settings programatically with PyQGIS? then I could write a plugin to switch between the proxy-settings.

EDIT1:

In the meantime i found a way to change the proxy settings of QGIS but still it's not working.

With this code I can change the settings:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl, QSettings
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkRequest, QNetworkProxy
from qgis.core import QgsNetworkAccessManager

my_settings={"Proxy enabled": u'proxy/proxyEnabled', "Proxy Host ": u'proxy/proxyHost', "Proxy Port": u'proxy/proxyPort'}
fiddler={"Proxy enabled": True, "Proxy Host ": "localhost", "Proxy Port": 8888}
freiburg={"Proxy enabled": True, "Proxy Host ": "192.168.95.165", "Proxy Port": 8080}
aus={"Proxy enabled": False, "Proxy Host ": "192.168.95.165", "Proxy Port": 8080}

current_choice=aus

s = QSettings() #getting proxy from qgis options settings

for key, val in my_settings.iteritems():
    #print str(key)+":"+str(val)
    settings_key=key
    #print str(settings_key)
    # Get user defined current setting
    for key2, val2 in current_choice.iteritems():
        if key2==settings_key:
            #print key
            #print val
            settings_val=val2
    current_setting = s.value(str(val).decode('unicode-escape'))
    #print str(val).decode('unicode-escape')
    #print str(key)+": "+str(current_setting)
    s.setValue(unicode(str(val)), settings_val)
s.sync()

# procedure to set proxy if needed

proxyEnabled = s.value("proxy/proxyEnabled", "")
proxyType = s.value("proxy/proxyType", "" )
proxyHost = s.value("proxy/proxyHost", "" )
proxyPort = s.value("proxy/proxyPort", "" )
proxyUser = s.value("proxy/proxyUser", "" )
proxyPassword = s.value("proxy/proxyPassword", "" )
if proxyEnabled == "true": # test if there are proxy settings
   proxy = QNetworkProxy()
   if proxyType == "DefaultProxy":
       proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.DefaultProxy)
   elif proxyType == "Socks5Proxy":
       proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.Socks5Proxy)
   elif proxyType == "HttpProxy":
       proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy)
   elif proxyType == "HttpCachingProxy":
       proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.HttpCachingProxy)
   elif proxyType == "FtpCachingProxy":
       proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.FtpCachingProxy)
   proxy.setHostName(proxyHost)
   proxy.setPort(int(proxyPort))
   proxy.setUser(proxyUser)
   proxy.setPassword(proxyPassword)
   QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy)
```

This works so far as I can see the changed settings in the QGIS UI (settings->options).

The settings are also written to the windows registry but the changes won't have any effect until i click the OK button in the QGIS settings dialog.

You can test this by setting the proxy programmatically to some proxy-settings that should prevent QGIS from accessing the internet (e.g. localhost:98765) and try to load and pan through a wms-layer.
Any idea what's missing?

Edit2:
I just piped the output from qgis to a file and had a look at what is going on when I change the proxy-settings using the GUI:

```
src/core/qgsnetworkaccessmanager.cpp: 364: (setupDefaultProxyAndCache) [9134ms] setting proxy 3 192.168.95.165:8080 /
src/core/qgsnetworkaccessmanager.cpp: 167: (setFallbackProxyAndExcludes) [0ms] proxy settings: (type:HttpProxy host: 192.168.95.165:8080, user:, password:not set
```

So there are two functions called (setupDefaultProxyAndCache and setFallbackProxyAndExcludes). Perhaps something like that has to be done when using pyQGIS to change the settings?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Setting proxy parameter in qgis plugins. How to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041066/setting-proxy-parameter-in-qgis-plugins-how-to)

Comment: I think that this solution works only for requests done by a specific plugin but not as a general proxy setting for QGIS. I need the proxy settings to get my WMS-layers loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved. QgsNetworkAccessManager had to be set to the new values**:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkRequest, QNetworkProxy

my_settings={"Proxy enabled": u'proxy/proxyEnabled', "Proxy Host ": u'proxy/proxyHost', "Proxy Port": u'proxy/proxyPort'}
fiddler={"Proxy enabled": True, "Proxy Host ": "localhost", "Proxy Port": 8888}
freiburg={"Proxy enabled": True, "Proxy Host ": "192.168.95.165", "Proxy Port": 8080}
aus={"Proxy enabled": False, "Proxy Host ": "192.168.95.165", "Proxy Port": 8080}

current_choice=aus

s = QSettings() #getting proxy from qgis options settings

for key, val in my_settings.iteritems():
    settings_key=key
    for key2, val2 in current_choice.iteritems():
        if key2==settings_key:
            settings_val=val2
    current_setting = s.value(str(val).decode('unicode-escape'))
    s.setValue(unicode(str(val)), settings_val)
s.sync()

proxyEnabled = s.value("proxy/proxyEnabled", "")
proxyType = s.value("proxy/proxyType", "" )
proxyHost = s.value("proxy/proxyHost", "" )
proxyPort = s.value("proxy/proxyPort", "" )
proxyUser = s.value("proxy/proxyUser", "" )
proxyPassword = s.value("proxy/proxyPassword", "" )
proxy = QNetworkProxy()
#setting HttpPtoxy
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy)

proxy.setHostName(proxyHost)
proxy.setPort(int(proxyPort))
proxy.setUser(proxyUser)
proxy.setPassword(proxyPassword)
QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy)
network_manager=QgsNetworkAccessManager.instance()
stringlist= ""
network_manager.setupDefaultProxyAndCache ()
network_manager.setFallbackProxyAndExcludes(proxy, stringlist)
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing these keys changed the settings in both the GUI and the Windows Registry of QGIS 2.14 Essen using your code above in the Python Console:

```
u'proxy/proxyEnabled', u'proxy/proxyExcludedUrls', u'proxy/proxyHost', u'proxy/proxyPassword', u'proxy/proxyPort', u'proxy/proxyType', u'proxy/proxyUser'
```

And at the end add:

```
QSettings.sync()
```

Comment: I just tried calling QSettings().sync() at the end of my code but still the same. only if i open the settings and click the OK-Button the changes are applied.

Comment: I can change the settings in the GUI and the registry but the settings still don't have any effect until i hit the OK-button in the settings dialog