# Accessing WFS data through proxy in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, wfs, qgis-2, proxy

I use QGIS 2.18.4 with an Osgeo4W install, W7 x64.

The code below works fine without a proxy :

```
import urllib
params = {
    'service': 'WFS',
    'version': '2.0.0',
    'request': 'GetFeature',
    'typename': 'regbio',
    'srsname': 'EPSG:2154'
}
uri = 'http://ws.carmencarto.fr/WFS/119/fxx_ref?' + urllib.unquote(urllib.urlencode(params))
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'ma couche wfs', 'WFS')
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print u"The layer %s is not valid" %vlayer.name()
idx = vlayer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('NOM_DOMAIN')
uv = vlayer.dataProvider().uniqueValues(idx)
uv.sort()
for i, item in enumerate(uv):
    print i, item
```

The result is :

```
0 alpin
1 atlantique
2 continental
3 mediterraneen
```

The problem I'm having is that I cannot get the same result when a proxy is used.

With a proxy, I use the code of this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37757921
However, the retrieved data are the html code.

Now, I wish to have the same result as the first code, but through a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this post : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/214915/93097, just add the following code for, according to the QgsNetworkAccessManager class instructions, setup the NetworkAccessManager according to the user's settings :

```
network_manager=QgsNetworkAccessManager.instance()
network_manager.setupDefaultProxyAndCache()
```

Working code :

```py
import urllib

network_manager = QgsNetworkAccessManager.instance()
network_manager.setupDefaultProxyAndCache()
params = {
    "service": "WFS",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "request": "GetFeature",
    "typename": "regbio",
    "srsname": "EPSG:2154"
}
params_unquote = urllib.unquote(urllib.urlencode(params))
uri = f"http://ws.carmencarto.fr/WFS/119/fxx_ref?{params_unquote}"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "my wfs layer", "WFS")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print(f"The layer {vlayer.name()} is not valid")

idx = vlayer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("NOM_DOMAIN")
uv = vlayer.dataProvider().uniqueValues(idx)
uv.sort()
for i, item in enumerate(uv):
    print(i, item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem to this and couldn't get the QgsNetworkAccessManager to work.
Used this instead:

```
from PyQt5 import QtNetwork

 

##Proxy Setting via QtNetwork

proxy = QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy()

proxy.setType(QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy)

proxy.setHostName("proxyexample.com")#without http/https

proxy.setPort(0000)#as integer

QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy)
```

Maybe it's also a hint for someone else.